# Are there test executables that Monero does not run?

Tags: testnet

For instance core-proxy is an executable under tests and is listed under `enabled-tests`  but has no `add_test` call in its CMakeLists.txt. I noticed it with some other folders as well like daemon_tests. Is this intended or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few. core_proxy is one. The clt and srv in net_load_tests are others. The C++ functional tests is another. I think that's the whole list.